# how to remove index.php through htaccess [Advanced]

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using codeigniter. There is always a way to remove index.php from url. The code is following for htaccess and it works fine.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

But the PROBLEM is: we still can access the website with index.php like following URLS.

Both are accessible:

```
 http://www.yoursite.com/index.php/cat/subcat 
 http://www.yoursite.com/cat/subcat
```

a forced removal of index.php is possible through htaccess? I actually dont want google to have both duplicate copies of same page. Any suggestion is welcomed

Comment: Would the site still work if you force a 301 redirect from `index.php/whatever` URIs to the `/whatever` URI? Or would that cause an infinite redirect loop in Apache? *Not sure*

Comment: 301 redirect cause infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?(.*) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

This checks that `/index.php` exists on the initial request (not just the rewritten request) and then redirects to the URL-path that follows if it is. By specifically checking against `THE_REQUEST` you avoid a redirect loop.

The trailing slash is optional, so it will also catch requests for `/index.php`.

Change the `302` (temporary) to `301` (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK.